# applicationhost.config inside hidden .vs folder

Tags: visual-studio, iis, applicationhost

can some help me because i am really confused. 
Using Visual studio, in my App folder i have a hidden folder named *.vs*, inside another folder *config* and next an *applicationhost.config*.

This config file, when used and for who is important to have? 
If i published my web app thought IIS, this file used in someway?

I can see that inside this config file exist node *applicationPools* and *sites* like this that IIS have. So why this config file have global settings for IIS and is stored inside my Apps folder and not somewhere more 'outside'?

When i run local my app this config used? Or only when is on IIS, or both?

I really have no idea why and how use *applicationhost.config* but if i wanted to change user credentials that App run what should change?

```
        <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeLoader="v4.0">
           <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="username" password="password" />
        </applicationPoolDefaults>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not shure if you are locally testing your website using *IIS* or rather *IIS Express*.

- The file in .vs is used to configure **IIS Express**, when you start your website from Visual Studio.
- When you publish your app to *IIS* this file is **ignored**.

If you whant to publish settings for IIS, you can include those in the section `<system.webServer>` in your **Web.config** file. Those settings will then be added to the IIS configuration, you deploy to.

Hope this makes things a bit clearer.