# Configuring log file fields in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, logging, iis-express

I'm dealing with log files and calculating the traffic usage of each website. The default logging is missing my required fields (`cs-host`, `sc-bytes`, `cs-bytes`). While I'm able to change these configuration in `Logging` section of IIS which I can select the fields I want to include or exclude in my logging. I couldn't find any way to change these configuration for IIS Express. Is there anyway to define the fields I want to include in the log in IIS express?

Either using a GUI like the `Logging` in IIS configuration, Command line code, or just editing a configuration file?

[image: IIS Log file configuration]

I found the IIS Express logFile configuration but in there, but couldn't find anything about adding the fields  there:

`%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`

which has logFile configuration in `SiteDefaults`:

```
<siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs"/>
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
</siteDefaults>
```

Comment: Does changing  this setting as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/) help ?

Comment: There is an IIS Express management console, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/

Comment: @Subbu I actually have read this before but this time I read it more thoroughly and I found the solution. `logExtFileFlags` Attribute of the `logFile` is what  I was looking for. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Great question.  Thought I would add,  you may find applicationhost.config in a hidden .vs folder under your solution.... Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174629/applicationhost-config-inside-hidden-vs-folder)

Answer (score 3):

To have a complete answer: you must first locate the `applicationhost.config` that corresponds to your site, and then edit the [`<logFile>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/) section. It can either be defined in `<siteDefaults>` to apply the same settings to all sites, or it can be defined for each `<site>` section.

To configure the default categories, you can use the `logExtFileFlags` attribute:

> The **logExtFileFlags** attribute can be one or more of the following values. If you specify more than one value, separate them with a comma (,).

In your case, you'll want `Host`, `BytesRecv` and `BytesSent`.

To add custom fields, you can use the [`<customFields>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/customfields/) subsection.

Here's a complete example:

```xml
<logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%AppData%\Microsoft\IISExpressLogs" 
 enabled="true" flushByEntryCountW3CLog="2" 
 logExtFileFlags="Host, BytesRecv, BytesSent">
  <customFields>
    <add logFieldName="custom-UUID" sourceType="RequestHeader" sourceName="UUID" />
  </customFields>
</logFile>
```